# How to have TeeChart left Custom Axis Title, with no labels, up tight against the chart and sized so axis title labels not clipped

Tags: teechart, yaxis

Delphi XE 10.2

TeeChartPro V2020.29.200113 32bit FMX

I am trying to have a left axis with no labels just a Title at 0 Degrees with the tile right justifed against the chart. Furthermore I would like to size the Charts Left Margin to be the size of the widest Left Axis Title so there is no clipping.

My current setup is that I have set the TChartAxis.Labels to False and TChartAxis.Title.Angle to zero which produces the attached chart.

How do I get the Axis Title to be up tight against the chart as shown with the arrow in the image?

How do I dynamically resize the TChart Left Margin to not clip any TChartAxis Titles as user resizes the chart?

[image]